# Constructor + Inheritance support

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am fairly new to Inheritance, and I'm not sure if I am doing it right but I seem to be on the right track. The program runs fine except the output I am getting isn't right. I think the problem is to do with my constructors.

```
public class Person {

    protected static String name;
    protected static int birthYear;

    public Person(String name, int birthYear) {
    }

    public String name (String n) {
        n = name;
        return n;
    }

    public int birthYear (int bY) {
        bY = birthYear;
        return bY;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(name + birthYear);
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {

    protected String major;

    public Student(String name, int birthYear, String major) {
        super(name, birthYear);
        major = "";
    }

    public String major(String maj) {
        maj = major;
        return maj;
    }

    public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        return super.toString() + major;
    }

}

public class Instructor extends Person {

    protected static int salary;

    public Instructor(String name, int birthYear, int salary) {
        super(name, birthYear);
        salary = 0;
    }

    public int salary(int sal) {
    sal = salary;
    return sal;
    }

    public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        return super.toString() + salary;
    }

}

public class PersonTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p = new Person("Perry", 1959);
        Student s = new Student("Sylvia", 1979, "Computer Science");
        Instructor e = new Instructor("Edgar", 1969, 65000);

        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println("Expected: Person[name=Perry,birthYear=1959]");

        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("Expected:" +        
        "Student[super=Person[name=Sylvia,birthYear=1979],major=Computer]");

        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Expected:" +    "Instructor[super=Person[name=Edgar,birthYear=1969],salary=65000.0]");
}
```

}

OUTPUT I AM GETTING:

```
null0
Expected: Person[name=Perry,birthYear=1959]
null0null
Expected: Student[super=Person[name=Sylvia,birthYear=1979],major=Computer     Science]
null00
Expected: Instructor[super=Person[name=Edgar,birthYear=1969],salary=65000.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your constructor in `Person` to:

```
public Person(String name, int birthYear) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
}
```

Currently, the constructor has an empty body, so when you call `super(name, birthYear);` in the subclass constructor, nothing actually happens.

Your `Student` constructor also has an error. You forgot to initialize the `major` field.

```
public Student(String name, int birthYear, String major) {
    super(name, birthYear);
    this.major = major;
}
```

You have the same problem in the `Instructor` constructor...

```
public Instructor(String name, int birthYear, int salary) {
    super(name, birthYear);
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Finally, you need to take away the `static` keywords before the fields in `Person`. This is because `static` ensures, that there will always be one (and only one) instance of those fields *per class*, as opposed to one *per instance*, like you want it to be:

```
protected String name;
protected int birthYear;
```

Same thing for the `salary` field in `Instructor`.

Comment: @xOMGaShoe If my answer helped you, you should upvote it at the very least (it's on the upper left of every answer). And mark one of the answers in this question as correct.

Answer (score -1):

`n = name;` this causing your problem. It must be `name = n;`. All your setter function contain this problem, correct them all and tell me result.

Comment: will not any difference, he is not calling any setters.

Comment: Although this is 100 percent true, this doesn't answer the question directly, and should be more of a comment.